# How to pass React Native Component as a JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native

I want to use [react-native-intro-slider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-app-intro-slider) in my react native application to make the intro pages as a slider. I have already implemented the pages as react functional components (where I can import them and use, ex:- ). But it seems that react native slider takes an array of json objects as inputs.

**Ex:-**

```
const slides = [
  {
    key: 1,
    title: 'Title 1',
    text: 'Description.\nSay something cool',
    image: require('./assets/1.jpg'),
    backgroundColor: '#59b2ab',
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    title: 'Title 2',
    text: 'Other cool stuff',
    image: require('./assets/2.jpg'),
    backgroundColor: '#febe29',
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    title: 'Rocket guy',
    text: 'I\'m already out of descriptions\n\nLorem ipsum bla bla bla',
    image: require('./assets/3.jpg'),
    backgroundColor: '#22bcb5',
  }
];
```

Instead of above json objects I want to pass the already created pages (functional components) as an input array. Something similar to below code:

```
const slides = [
  {
    key: 1,
    <Page 1/>
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    <Page2 />
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    <Page3 />
  }
];
```

How can I do it, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not part of their API. But I suppose you could switch components in the renderItem function.

```
const slides = ["1", "2"];

const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
  switch(item) {
    case "1": return <Page1 />;
  }
};
```